# Exchange 2013 CU18 install fails with ADObjectAlreadyExistsException

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange, exchange-2013

I'm updating from Exchange 2013 RTM to Exchange 2013 CU18.

Exchange upgrade is failing currently with the following error...

> Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 Cumulative Update 18 Unattended Setup
>
> Copying Files... File copy complete. Setup will now collect additional
>   information needed for installation. Languages Mailbox role: Transport
>   service Client Access role: Front End Transport service Mailbox role:
>   Client Access service Mailbox role: Unified Messaging service Mailbox
>   role: Mailbox service Management tools Client Access role: Client
>   Access Front End service
>
> Performing Microsoft Exchange Server Prerequisite Check
>
> ```
> Configuring Prerequisites                                 COMPLETED
> Prerequisite Analysis                                     COMPLETED
> ```
>
> Configuring Microsoft Exchange Server
>
> ```
> Organization Preparation                                  FAILED
>  The following error was generated when "$error.Clear();
>     install-GlobalAddressLists -DomainController $RoleDomainController
> ```
>
> " was run:
>   "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectAlreadyExistsException: Ac
>   tive Directory operation failed on HOSTEX-1.mydomain.cloud. The object
>   'CN= Default Global Address List,CN=All Global Address
>   Lists,CN=Address Lists Contain er,CN=Hosted Exchange,CN=Microsoft
>   Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration ,DC=mydomain,DC=cloud' already
>   exists. ---> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.
>   DirectoryOperationException: The object exists.    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.ConstructResponse(Int32
>   messageId, LdapOperation operation, ResultAll resultType, TimeSpan
>   requestTimeOu t, Boolean exceptionOnTimeOut)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryReq
>   uest request, TimeSpan requestTimeout)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.PooledLdapConnection.SendRequest(Directo
>   ryRequest request, LdapOperation ldapOperation, Nullable`1
>   clientSideSearchTimeo ut, IActivityScope activityScope, String
>   callerInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.ExecuteModificationRequest
>   (ADObject entry, DirectoryRequest request, ADObjectId originalId,
>   Boolean emptyO bjectSessionOnException, Boolean isSync)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.AnalyzeDirectoryError(Pool
>   edLdapConnection connection, DirectoryRequest request,
>   DirectoryException de, In t32 totalRetries, Int32 retriesOnServer)
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.ExecuteModificationRequest
>   (ADObject entry, DirectoryRequest request, ADObjectId originalId,
>   Boolean emptyO bjectSessionOnException, Boolean isSync)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.Save(ADObject
>   instanceToSa ve, IEnumerable`1 properties, Boolean bypassValidation)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.SystemConfiguration.ADConfigurationSessi
>   on.Save(ADConfigurationObject instanceToSave)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Deployment.InstallGlobalAddressLists.CreateD
>   efaultGal(ADObjectId defaultGal)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Deployment.InstallGlobalAddressLists.Interna
>   lProcessRecord()    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.b__b()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.InvokeRetryableFunc(String
>   fun cName, Action func, Boolean terminatePipelineIfFailed)".
>
> The Exchange Server setup operation didn't complete. More details can
>   be found in ExchangeSetup.log located in the
>   :\ExchangeSetupLogs folder.

Any help at all is appriciated!

Comment: Are you running the setup from Administor's CMD prompt?

Comment: Doh.... possibly not! seems to be progressing now! *facepalm*

Comment: Please add your response as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Run the setup from an administrative CMD prompt.  This will fix the error you are receiving and continue progression through the update.

Answer (score 0):

Please **stop** the installation process, we need to **upgrade Exchange 2013 CU15** and install **.NET Framework 4.6.2**, then upgrade to CU18.

More information, refer to: [**Exchange 2013 CU16 and Exchange 2016 CU5 .NET Framework Requirement**](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2017/03/27/exchange-2013-cu16-and-exchange-2016-cu5-net-framework-requirement/)

Comment: Windows updated have been kept up to date on the server in question and it doesn't fail prerequisites, as that article would suggest.

On that basis, do i still need CU15 first?

Comment: Does the installation process run prepare AD and schema now, or the CU18 installation is completed? If so and no error returns, check the .Net Framework version first, ensure it's 4.6.2.